# No password mask and wrong events after upgrading team developer 3 to 6

Tags: guptateamdeveloper

do you know why some class things changed after upgrading from 3.1 to 6.3 SP2?

For example our `Password fields` ... The `Format` property is `Class default` - correct is `Invisible`.

Thanks in Advance for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

Did you first save all your files as text ( .apt ), not Binary ( .apl or .app ) .
Best Tip: Don't use the 'Migration Wizard' .
After saving as Text, you should open each file in TD6.3 to do the conversion. Don't double click from File Explorer to open , but open from within TD itself.
Have done many upgrades this way , and never a problem.
Also , are you running on a TD6.3 certified O/S i.e. not Win XP , else unexpected results in conversion. See Compatibility Matrix to be sure: http://www.guptatechnologies.com/Products/App_Dev/TeamDeveloper/TeamDeveloperCompatibilityMatrix.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have a 50 MB APT file of the project which contains everything. I saved this as text in 3.1 and opened it in 6.3 SP2. And then as I said the password fields are not hidden anymore. And the performance is bad. Paint as background is lost and everything :-(
Do you have further ideas? Or maybe we can chat here or via skype? :-)

Comment: Being a 50 mB APT implies you have 'Merged' all the apl's first. ? You cant do this and then convert without loosing settings. - You must save each individual .apl ( and any .app's ) as Text ( do not 'Merge' anything ) . To save each apl as Text , 'Save As' --> Select 'save as Type' --> 'Text( *.apt )' --> your file name will revert to xxx.**apt** before you Save it , so change it at this point to xxx.**apl** --> Then click Save.  This way your .apl will Save as Text , but with a ',apl' prefix . From past experience , converting ( upgrading ) a Merged file will never work .

Answer (score 1):

Being a 50 mB APT implies you have 'Merged' all the apl's first. ? You cant do this and then convert without loosing settings. - You must save each individual .apl ( and any .app's ) as Text ( do not 'Merge' anything ) . To save each apl as Text , 'Save As' --> Select 'save as Type' --> 'Text( *.apt )' --> your file name will revert to xxx.**apt** before you Save it , so change it at this point to xxx.**apl** --> Then click Save.  This way your .apl will Save as Text , but with a ',apl' prefix . From past experience , converting ( upgrading ) a Merged file will never work .

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll check what I did wrong. I never clicked on "Merge". I think the software grows up with the time.

Comment: I have Windows 10 Pro without service pack. On compatibility list they say "starting with SP1" - maybe I can solve the problem by installing SP1 :-)